# MATLAB QUESTIONS on logical indexing and cell2struct function

Tags: matlab, indexing, logical-operators

First Question: 
Hello there!

I am trying to assign this vector

> `v(mod(v,2)~=0)=0`

The operations is supposed to replace odd numbers in a vector with 0. I am trying to assign this vector to result variable in a function.

something goes wrong when I try this
 function

```
 function [result1,result2] = myfunction(v)
 v(mod(v,2)==0)= 0; 
result1 = v;

v(mod(v,2)~=0) = 0; 
result2 = v; 
return
```

QUESTION 2:

I am trying to figure out an alternative way to express the the function cell2struct in for-loop format

for example,

if we have a cell array with 2 dimensions containing food labels. Their names, caloric count and price, each in one column. Can we write a function that's can transfer the information in cells to a struct that contain each of the fields above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Question #1

You are setting all even numbers to 0, but then you are using **this mutated result** to search for odd numbers and setting them to 0.  This will probably not give you what you intended as you are using a **modified** copy of the original vector, so it would be prudent that you keep a copy of the vector before doing each operation.

```
function [result1,result2] = myfunction(v)
vcopy = v; %// Make a copy
vcopy(mod(vcopy,2)==0)= 0; %// Find even numbers and set to 0 
result1 = vcopy;

vcopy = v; %// Make another copy
vcopy(mod(vcopy,2)~=0) = 0; %// Find odd numbers and set them to 0.
result2 = vcopy; 
return
```

## Question #2

Yup.  If you have a list of field names stored in `f` and their corresponding entities for each field stored in `c`, simply use a loop like so:

```
function [s] = my_cell2struct(c, f)
for idx = 1 : numel(f)
    s.(f{idx}) = c{idx};
end
```

The above code does no error checking, so you need to make sure that the total number of elements in `c` matches those of `f`.  Also, `c` and `f` must be cell arrays.  Notice that `s` wasn't declared at all in the function.  Also, using the dot operator combined with enclosing brackets and a string that goes inside the enclosing brackets allows you to dynamically create field names on the fly.  As such, for each string in `f`, we access the corresponding value stored in `c`, and we create a field name that contains this value.

Here's a reproducible example from the MathWorks documentation:

```
c = {'tree',37.4,'birch'};
f = {'category','height','name'};
s = cell2struct(c, f, 2)

s = 

    category: 'tree'
      height: 37.4000
        name: 'birch'
```

Notice that I use `cell2struct` here from native MATLAB to produce the above structure.  Doing the above `for` loop which is wrapped in a function called `my_cell2struct`, we get:

```
c = {'tree',37.4,'birch'};
f = {'category','height','name'};
s =  my_cell2struct(c, f)

s = 

    category: 'tree'
      height: 37.4000
        name: 'birch'
```